# Unswitching an Outlet

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet in a room that is switched and I would like to convert it to being always on. The way I can think of to do it is just to connect the load and the line in the switch box. Is there anything wrong with converting the outlet to being unswitched/always-on in this way?

Comment: Is it half-switched or completely? Are there other switched outlets on the circuit that you'd like to retain?

Comment: Why not just leave the switch in the on position? If you are having trouble with users operating the switch you can put on a cover over the switch. Some are magnetic some are attached by the screws. https://www.google.com/shopping/product/1866489953672921421?lsf=seller:8740,store:9671194313301135564&prds=oid:231782108169316970&q=shabbos+switch+cover&hl=en&ei=rYMCWe60JIz2jwOjoobwDA&lsft=cm_mmc%3DShopping-_-LIAs-_-D27E-_-100628705&lsft=gclid:Cj0KEQjwrYbIBRCgnY-OluOk89EBEiQAZER58moS-WRIeOxUl78qsgacktlD_PTMrNW7XeNTUmIdocYaAooa8P8HAQ

Comment: There is only one outlet on the switch, and it is only half.

I would leave it in the on position, but the switch with the outlet is actually a duplex.(I think that is what it is called when there are two switches in a single gang).  I am going to want to replace the duplex switch with a z-wave switch and I wouldn't have space for the outlet switch anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a normal single pole switch, then yes. Remove the switch, connect the line and load wires, cap it off and put a blank cover over the box.

As per the second question, no there is nothing wrong. Just do not leave a dead switch in the box or ever bury the box in the wall.